# UNION with all field names and nulls where names don't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fiddling around with this code to find all table names with all the fields that I need.

```
select t.name, c.name
from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t
on c.object_id = t.object_id
where c.name like '%ID%' 
     OR c.name like '%ID1%'
     OR c.name like '%ID2%'
     OR c.name like '%ID3%'
     OR c.name like '%ABC%'
     OR c.name like '%RTG%'
order by c.name
```

I am getting a couple hundred table names and field names.  Basically, I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to get my results like this:

```
select col1, col2, col3, null as col4 from table1
union all
select col1, col2, col3, null as col4 from table2
union all
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table3;
```

The challenge here is...I can type out the logic, but I'm dealing with hundreds of tables/fields, and It's really difficult to hard-code all of this logic.  I am using SQL Server Azure. Thoughts? Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. I significantly doubt that every one of your tables have identical definitions for **all** of their columns; and if they don't, then that is a design flaw unto itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I really recommend this, but you can use a scoping trick so all the subqueries are basically the same:

```
select t.*
from (values (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) v(a, b, c, d) cross apply
     (select a, b, c, d
      from table1
     ) t
union all
select t.*
from (values (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) v(a, b, c, d) cross apply
     (select a, b, c, d
      from table2
     ) t
. . .
```

Basically, the subquery will select values from the table *if they exist*.  Otherwise, it will fetch them from `v`.

EDIT:

Or as Martin points out:

```
select t.*
from (values (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) v(a, b, c, d) cross apply
     ((select a, b, c, d from table1
      ) union all
      (select a, b, c, d from table2
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) t
```

Comment: no need to to repeat the values clause. if the UNION ALL is done inside the CROSS APPLY it should be good for all branches

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . I'm trying to decide if I like either approach.  Part of me says "real cool -- it does the `union` and fills in missing values.  The other part says "yuck! too much of a hack of scoping rules."

Comment: Well, it's definitely a hack, but it does the job and that's good enough for me.

Comment: @asher . . . I can appreciate the need as well.  For instance, if the tables represent reports that are produced weekly, essentially the same, but might evolve over time (which is why they need to be in separate tables).